# Regular expression to match '\n' character

Tags: java, regex

I am having a string `"<?xml version=2.0><rss>Feed</rss>"` I wrote a regex to match this string as

```
"<?xml.*<rss.*</rss>"
```

But if the input string contains \n like `"\nFeed" doesn't work for the above regex.

How to modify my regex to include \n character between strings.

Comment: It all depends on where you want to catch `\n`.  After `<?xml`?  After `<rss`?

Comment: Please, to keep us all sane and safe, don't parse XML with regular expressions. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1907906

Comment: You need to use the `s` (*DOTALL*) modifier forcing the `.` to match newline sequences.

Comment: You can use  a [DOTALL option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) to let `.` also capture `\r` and `\n`: `"(?s)...."`. Mind that a Windows line break (CR+LF), "\r\n" would not work too.

Comment: Try `<\?xml.*<rss.*<\/rss>`. escape `?` and '/' by using escape character `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

The matching behavior of a dot can be controlled with a flag. It looks like in Java the default matching behavior for the dot is any character except the line terminators \r and \n.

I'm not a Java programmer, but usually using `(?s)` at beginning of a search string changes the matching behavior for a dot to any character including line terminators. So perhaps `"(?s)<?xml.*<rss.*</rss>"` works.

But better would be here to use `"<?xml.*?<rss[\s\S]*?</rss>"` as search string.

`\s` matches any whitespace character which includes line terminators and `\S` matches any non whitespace character. Both in square brackets results in matching any character.

For completness: `[\w\W]` matches also always any character.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine it with `(\\n)*`.  It is necessary to add an extra `\` because it is a special character. 
Another option is to execute `replaceAll("\\n","")` before executing the regex.

Comment: I added code formatting so we can read the answer as you intended it, but it's still a bad answer.  For one thing, `\n` is not the only character that `.` doesn't match.

Comment: Thank you for editing it, I published it with my mobile and I didn't remember the formatting character. And yes, you are right, those options are not good solutions, just workarounds for solving the mentioned `\n` problem